# Accessing localhost web server on my Mac from Android on same wifi

Tags: android, macos, networking

I've a web server running on my localhost 6464 port. I can access it from the same laptop. Now, I want to access it from my Android phone. Both are connected to same wifi router. Here are the some of the things I did:

1. I enabled 6464 port forwarding on my XFinity router.
2. I went to sharing on system preferences and enabled "Internet Sharing"
3. Also, the sharing screen shows the "Computers on your local network  can access your computer at: aaron2.local

I am trying to access it from my phone as http://aaron2.local:6464. The error says "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED".

I did ifconfig and found the IP to be 10.0.0.224, and I used the same IP address and the port number, same issue.

What else is needed to access.

Answer (score 0):

you need to config the webserver listen on 0.0.0.0. (google it how to based on what is your webserver)
also you need allow tcp incoming on port 6464 in your os firewall